# Class methods and instantiate

Tags: php

I am working on something. I am trying to  Create a class in config.php that contains a method to connect to the database.In dbConnectExample.php, instantiate that class and call the method. I am kinda getting confused because I am learning to others programming classes too. This is what I have so far;

```
    <?php # Scripts 6.3 - Rectangle.php

Class Rectangle {

//Declare the attributes:
public $width = 0;
public $height = 0;

//Method to set the dimensions.
Function set_size($w = 0, $h = 0) {
        $this->width = $w;
        $this->height = $h;
}

//Method to calculate and return the area.
function get_area() {
    return ($this->width * $this->height);
    }

// Method to calculate and return the perimeter.
function get_perimeter() {
    return ( ( $this->width + $this->height) * 2 );
    }

    //Method to determine if the rectangle
    //is also a square
    function is_square() {

    if ($this->width == $this->height) {
    return true; //Square
    } else {
        return false; //Not a square
    }
  }

} //End of Rectangle class.
```

I know I am creating a class with a method. I am just confused to connect to a database you go like this;

```
    //Connect to the database
$DBConnect = @new mysqli("localhost", "valerie_2shuawna", "norris");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
      . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
      . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
$DBName = "config.php";
    @$DBConnect->select_db($DBName)
         Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
         . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
         . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";

$DBConnect->close();
```

But I am suppose to instantiate that class and call the method. and then the config it is suppose to contain a method to connect to the database. If someone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong and maybe explain so I am not so confused I would be grateful it.

Comment: Format your code properly, please. I am talking about indents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple class:

```
// Database.php

class Database
{
    public static function getDbo($dbName)
    {
        $dbo = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception(
                "<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
               . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
               . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>"
            );
        }

        if (!$dbo->select_db($dbName)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
                . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
                . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"
            );
        }

        return $dbo;
    }
}

// SomeFile.php

require_once 'Database.php';

try {
    $dbo = Database::getDbo();

    // If I made it this far then I can start querying
    $dbo->query('SELECT stuff FROM table');

    // etc.

} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want include_once("config.php").

The config.php should include either 1)database settings like username and password or could 2) take those values and actually perform the connection

Start off by creating a php file that includes config.php.

You should be able to see from the config.php included file "a method to connect to the database."

Make sure that you call it. Hope that helps! :)

Also to instantiate classes use the new keyword like

```
 $square = new Square();
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your database connection code in a function, then wrap that in a class. Stick that class in config.php. Instantiate that class in dbConnectExample.php (see the commend from @jakx).